# Troubleshoot- Bootstrap not responding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Im working on a bootstrap blog/site and Im having some issues. Maybe an extra pair of eyes can help me here. Its super simple right now and just alot of placeholder text but its not responding to the screen size. I do have some other styles but nothing serious and doesn't override bootstrap. Just mainly b=background colors and heights. Im not sure why its not working. I should mention, im only using the cdn because i'll be working with google blogger. Any suggestions, would be great. Thank you.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
     <title>MIM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
    <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="socialMedia text-center">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!--Social Media Section-->
        <a href='http://facebook.com/MommyinMKE' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>facebook</span></a>
     <a href='http://twitter.com/MommyinMKE' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>twitter</span></a>
     <a href='https://www.instagram.com/keilalleist/' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>instagram</span></a>
     <a href='http://pinterest.com/keilaleist' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>pinterest</span></a>
     <a href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNMVemcUPuscLSNyeXZje8Q' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>youtube</span></a>
     <a href='https://www.bloglovin.com/blogs/mommy-in-milwaukee-12557621' target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class='smg-label'>bloglovin</span></a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
       [widget for header placed here]
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="navBar">
       <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <!--Nav Section-->
        <h2>NavBar</h2>
        <span>.col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="Carasouel">
       <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <!--Carasouel-->
        <h2>Carasouel</h2>
        <span>.col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
   <div class="sideBar text-center">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <!--sideBar Section-->
        <h2>Side Bar</h2>
        <span>col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="smallCarasoul text-center">
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <!--Blog Content-->
        <h2>Small Carasoul</h2>
        <span>col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
   
      <div class="blogContent text-center">
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <!--Blog Content-->
        <h2>Blog Content</h2>
        <span>col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="socialMedia2 text-center">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!--Social Media-->
        <h2>Social Media</h2>
        <span>.col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="instragram text-center">
       <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!--Instagram-->
        <h2>Instagram</h2>
        <span>.col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="footer text-center">
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <!--Footer Section-->
        <h2>Footer</h2>
        <span>col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

```
body {
 color: #343434;
 font:normal normal 13px Open Sans;
 line-height: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 text-transform: none;    font-weight: 400;
}

p {
 font-size:13px;
 line-height:26px;
}

a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#777777;
}

a:hover {
 color:#000000
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width:1100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}


.container .row .socialMedia .col-xs-12 {
  background-color:#eec7bc;
  height:48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.socialMedia a i {
 font-size: 11px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 line-height:48px;
 color:#ffffff;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.socialMedia a {
 padding-left: 50px;
}

.socialMedia a { 
 color:#ffffff; 
}

.socialMedia a:hover { 
  color:#777777; 
  text-decoration: none;

}

.container .row .socialMedia2 .col-xs-12 {
  background-color:#eec7bc;
  height:100px;
}

.container .row .navBar .col-xs-12 {
  border-top: 2px solid #eec7bc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eec7bc;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.container .row .navBar .col-xs-12 h2{
 margin-top:0px;
}

.container .row .Carasouel .col-xs-12 {
 background-color:gray;
 height:540px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}

.container .row .smallCarasoul .col-xs-12 {
  background-color:gray;
  height:470px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
 }

.container .row .sideBar .col-xs-12 {
 background-color:red;
 height:1000px;
}

.container .row .blogContent .col-xs-12 {
 background-color:blue;
 height:500px;
}



/*************************************************
*   10. Tablet                                   *
*************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 960px) {
    .socialMedia a {
     padding-left: 20px;
    }
}

 /*************************************************
 *  Mobile Portrait                              *
 *************************************************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .socialMedia span {
    display: none;
 }

.socialMedia a {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
}

/*************************************************
*   10. Landscape                                *
*************************************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .socialMedia a i {
      font-size: 14px;
     }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't replicate the issue. Please give us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: can you please attach css/main.css code here..

Comment: It seems to work perfectly for me (it readjusts to viewport size). Like others said, can you provide the full CSS?

Comment: no problem with your code..provide additional css

Comment: Thanks, just added the CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `.container` to a fixed width of 1100px which is making it stick to that width and not going any narrower. You should use `max-width: 1100px` instead.

Comment: Of course I did..lol!! Thank you. Sometimes you stare at the same thing over and over, you miss the simple things. Again thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Don't worry though, you'll begin to notice those small things much quicker.